# Loading XML file with attributes into JQuery array... array is empty

Tags: jquery, arrays, xml

I'm hoping this is a fairly simple solution, but it's taken me all day to get this far, and I'm having a hard time figuring out what's still wrong.

I have an XML file called JobTagsList.xml:

```
<Tags><Tag Tag="consolidated"/><Tag Tag="test"/></Tags>
```

And an ASP.NET Webforms page with the following JQuery code (including all the script, just in case):

```
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/tag-it.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var isrecurring = $("#<%=IsRecurringJob.ClientID %>").prop('checked');
//            console.log(isrecurring);
            if (isrecurring) {
                $(".showwhenrecurring").show();
            } else {
                $(".showwhenrecurring").hide();
            }

            var jobid = $("#<%=JobID.ClientID %>");
            if (jobid.val() != null && jobid.val() != '') {
            } else {
                $(".hidewhennew").hide();
            }


        });

        //tags handling starts here
        function split(val) {
            return val.split(/,\s*/);
        }
        function extractLast(term) {
            return split(term).pop();
        }

        $(function () {
            var tagslist = new Array();
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "../XML/JobTagsList.xml",
                dataType: "xml",
                success: function (xml) {

                    //but if it's multible items then loop
                    $(xml).find('Tag').each(function () {
                        tagslist.push($(this).attr('Tag'));
                    });
                }
            });

            $("#<% =txtTags.ClientID %>")
                .on("keydown", function (event) {
                    if (event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
                        $(this).autocomplete("instance").menu.active) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                    }
                });

            $("#<% =txtTags.ClientID %>").tagit({
                availableTags: tagslist,
                // This will make Tag-it submit a single form value, as a comma-delimited field.
                singleField: true,
                singleFieldNode: $("#<% =txtTags.ClientID %>")
            });

        });

        function fixform() {
            if (opener.document.getElementById("PageForm").target != "_blank") return;
            opener.document.getElementById("PageForm").target = "";
            opener.document.getElementById("PageForm").action = opener.location.href;
        }
    </script>
```

The code compiles without an error, but the tagslist array is empty, according to the Chrome debugger, when it should have two items in it (['test', 'consolidated']). Please help. :)

Comment: In your success callback, have you tried debugging the xml variable to see what is returned?  If it does return back the xml, it might be as a string.  In that case, you would have to parse it with something like var xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml ); and then follow that up with var $xml = $( xmlDoc ); and then use $xml.find('Tag').each for your loop.

Comment: Many thanks! Turns out it was returning a document object, so that wasn't the issue, but in the process of figuring that out, I renamed the variable, and that seemed to fix it (at least after I stepped through the code again. Didn't work at first, then I stepped through the code, and then it did). :)

Comment: Ah JavaScript.  Glad you got it working.